# How do I get the zsh plugin colored-man-pages to work for git?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just installed the `colored-man-pages` plugin from [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/colored-man-pages/colored-man-pages.plugin.zsh). How do I get the colored man pages to show/work with `git <command> --help`?

Comment: Go up a page from your link and it tells you: "You can also try to color other pages by prefixing the respective command with colored:" `colored git help clone`.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno - Awesome! Is there a way to make that the default for a normal `git clone --help`? FYI: I would mark this as answered but you put it in a comment.

Comment: Based on the script, you could write a `function` that overrides `git` and checks to see if it should run `colored git ...`. Maybe it will always work to insert `colored` naïvely the way that script does for `man` and a few other commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go up a page from your link and it tells you: "You can also try to color other pages by prefixing the respective command with colored:"

```
colored git help clone
```